# How to change in elegant way List<> structure

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am using LINQ to entitiy in my project.

I have this LINQ:

```
    var result = (from inspArch in inspectionArchives
             from inspAuth in inspArch.InspectionAuthority               
             select new 
             {
                Id = inspArch.Id,
                clientId = inspArch.CustomerId,
                authId = inspAuth.Id
             }).ToList();
```

After LINQ is executed **result** has this value :

[image]

Is there any elegant way (for example using LINQ or change above existing LINQ) to create from the list above, new list like that:

[image]

Comment: use group by Clientid

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I tryed but i need to create array from leftand right sides

Comment: @Michael - Check my update for your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `group by` and you can apply `String.Join` on the resulting `IGrouping`:-

```
 var result = (from inspArch in inspectionArchives
              from inspAuth in inspArch.InspectionAuthority 
              group new { inspArch, inspAuth } by inspArch.CustomerId into g           
              select new 
              {
                  Id = String.Join(",",g.Select(x => x.inspArch.Id),
                  clientId = x.Key,
                  authId = String.Join(",",g.Select(x => x.inspAuth.Id)
              }).ToList();
```

The tricky part here is to group both objects i.e. `new { inspArch, inspAuth }` because we need to access properties from both.

**Update:**

Since this is entity framework, it won't be able to translate the method `String.Join` to SQL, so we can bring back the grouped object to memory using `AsEnumerable` and then project it like this:-

```
var result = (from inspArch in inspectionArchives
              from inspAuth in inspArch.InspectionAuthority 
              group new { inspArch, inspAuth } by inspArch.CustomerId into g
              select g).AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(g => new 
                        {
                            Id = String.Join(",",g.Select(x => x.inspArch.Id),
                            clientId = x.Key,
                            authId = String.Join(",",g.Select(x => x.inspAuth.Id)
                        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't built this to see if it compiles, but this should work.  You need to aggregate the Id and AuthId fields.

```
var result = (from inspArch in inspectionArchives
         from inspAuth in inspArch.InspectionAuthority               
         select new 
         {
            Id = inspArch.Id,
            clientId = inspArch.CustomerId,
            authId = inspAuth.Id
         })
.GroupBy(g => g.clientId)
.select(s => new {
    Id = string.Join(",", s.Select(ss => ss.Id.ToString())),
    ClientId = s.Key,
    AuthId = string.Join(",", s.Select(ss => ss.authId.ToString()).Distinct()),
}).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for post.
I get this exception:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. 

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: LINQ to Entities can't translate .ToString() into SQL, you will need to find a way to convert Id to a string (if it isn't already) before using it in a select statement, or remove ToString, as I believe string.Join will convert it for you

Comment: @Michael, I wasn't sure about the need for the .ToString().  You probably can remove it.  Another possibility I think is to force the query to run and then handle the results.  I think you can do that by putting a .ToList() just before the .GroupBy(...).

Comment: @user2023861,the problem not with the ToString() method the problem with String.Join( )  see the error above.

Comment: @Michael, did you try adding the ToList() just before the GroupBy()?  This is similar to the other answer on this page which uses .AsEnumerable().  It forces the query to return at that point.  From that point on, the data is in-memory and you can use string.join or any other .Net method on it.